# the SDK Manager does not open

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Shows this message in event log:

```
(ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)
```

note: this problem happened when i updated my AS

Comment: Go to that folder mentioned and see if your SDK exists. You may have installed your SDK in another location.

Comment: I have searched on that file (android.bat),it's not exist . The AppData folder not exist at all !

Comment: AppData folder is hidden in windows by default, you have to make your folder layout options to show hidden folders and files.

Comment: Hi are you using a Windows system, or linux?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky u was right i have found the AppData folder but the file android.bat was in another location so, i copied  it in the right place  .. thank you